# Clone and document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a form with some required fields. I use code like this to notify the user when they are blank:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input.required:text').focus(function() {
        $(this).css({'background-color': '#FFF'});
    });
    $('input.required:text').blur(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).css({'background-color': 'rgba(222, 41, 30, 1)'});
        }
    });
})
```

The problem is that I also have an "add" button that will clone a hidden form by running this function:

```
function addlocation() {
    var clone = $('div.location-info-new').clone();
    clone.addClass('location-info');
    clone.find('form').addClass('ready');
    clone.removeClass('location-info-new');
    clone.appendTo('div.locations');
    clone.find('input.required:text').focus(function() {
        $(this).css({'background-color': '#FFF'});
    });
    clone.find('input.required').each(function (i, v) {
        $(this).css({'background-color': 'rgba(222, 41, 30, 1)'});
    });
}
```

I had to add in the background-color changes here or else they didn't work at all on the cloned form. There is still one problem. The fields will properly show in red initially on the new form, and they will even change to white when they get focus. Unfortunately, if the user gives the input box focus, doesn't type anything, and removes focus, the input box doesn't change back to red. On the original form, this works properly.

Why isn't the background-color changes from document.ready applying to my cloned form?

Comment: You should really provide a jsFiddle

Comment: Use [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead. "Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the elements were added dynamically after you have subscribed to the existing elements. You can use jQuery on function to subscribe to every element that is on the form initially and that will be created.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('focus', 'input.required:text', function() {
        $(this).css({'background-color': '#FFF'});
    });
    $(document).on('blur','input.required:text', (function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).css({'background-color': 'rgba(222, 41, 30, 1)'});
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. That works well, although I still needed to set the background-color to red for the initial value on cloned forms.

Answer (score 2):

> Why isn't the background-color changes from document.ready applying to my cloned form?

Because the new elements don't have this event handler bound to them. You are binding the `focus` event handler:

```
clone.find('input.required:text').focus(function() {
    $(this).css({'background-color': '#FFF'});
});
```

but you are not binding the `blur` event handler. There a couple of ways to solve your problem:

**Manually bind the `blur` event handler**

Just add

```
clone.find('input.required:text').blur(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        $(this).css({'background-color': 'rgba(222, 41, 30, 1)'});
    }
});
```

to your function.

**Use `.clone` correctly**

If you look at the documentation, you can see that [`.clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) accepts a boolean argument which enables the copy of data and event handlers as well. So you can use

```
var clone = $('div.location-info-new').clone(true);
```

instead and remove

```
clone.find('input.required:text').focus(function() { ... });
```

**Use event delegation**

Which is extensively explained in the jQuery tutorial: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 1):

You CAN NOT trigger the event directly to the element you added programmatically.

use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind function to your element.

change your code to this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input.required:text').on("focus", function() {
        $(this).css({'background-color': '#FFF'});
    });
    $('input.required:text').on("blur", function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).css({'background-color': 'rgba(222, 41, 30, 1)'});
        }
    });
})
```